# NSKeyedUnarchiver with custom Objects

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nskeyedarchiver

I have a question about NSKeyedUnarchiver, NSMutableArray and self-created classes. The data is stored by NSKeyedArchiver to user defaults. When the data load into the user defaults will be printed to the console of the data stream. I want to unpack the data into an array, the array will be empty.
Maybe someone of you knows how I save the array or the array load.

Thank you.

Greetings,
Schumi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through [`this documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) first. But basically, To enable archiving on custom class objects you will have to adopt the `NSCoding` protocol and implement `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` methods.